# How to check for a key with value type array with taocpp json

Tags: c++, json

Need to find if an array exists in a JSON object using taocpp-json. It is easy to use optional for finding ints and boolean etc., but if the value is an array, I cannot find out how to do it.

I tried:

```
v.optional<std::vector<tao::json::value>>("fields");
```

But this gives me a compiler error!

On msvc:

```
C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2017\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1416~1.270\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP  -IC:\devel\cpp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /EHsc /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG -MD   -std:c++17 /showIncludes /Fosrc\CMakeFiles\tabgen.dir\file_manager.cpp.obj /Fdsrc\CMakeFiles\tabgen.dir\ /FS -c ..\src\file_manager.cpp
c:\devel\cpp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\tao\json\basic_value.hpp(1308): error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'void' to 'std::optional<std::vector<tao::json::basic_value<tao::json::traits>,std::allocator<_Ty>>>'
        with
        [
            _Ty=tao::json::basic_value<tao::json::traits>
        ]
c:\devel\cpp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\tao\json\basic_value.hpp(1308): note: Expressions of type void cannot be converted to other types
..\src\file_manager.cpp(24): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::optional<std::vector<tao::json::basic_value<tao::json::traits>,std::allocator<_Ty>>> tao::json::basic_value<tao::json::traits>::optional<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>,char[7]>(const K (&)) const' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=tao::json::basic_value<tao::json::traits>,
            K=char [7]
        ]
..\src\file_manager.cpp(24): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::optional<std::vector<tao::json::basic_value<tao::json::traits>,std::allocator<_Ty>>> tao::json::basic_value<tao::json::traits>::optional<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>,char[7]>(const K (&)) const' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Ty=tao::json::basic_value<tao::json::traits>,
            K=char [7]
        ]
c:\devel\cpp\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\tao\json\events/virtual_base.hpp(69): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'tao::basic_binary_view<std::byte>' being compiled
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\filesystem(2392): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::chrono::time_point<std::filesystem::_File_time_clock,std::filesystem::_File_time_clock::duration>' being compiled
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\type_traits(616): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::basic_string_view<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>>' being compiled
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xstring(2124): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_convertible<const _StringViewIsh &,std::basic_string_view<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>>>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _StringViewIsh=const wchar_t *
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xstring(2122): note: see reference to variable template 'const bool conjunction_v<std::is_convertible<wchar_t const * const &,std::basic_string_view<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t> > >,std::negation<std::is_convertible<wchar_t const * const &,wchar_t const *> > >' being compiled
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\xstring(2281): note: see reference to alias template instantiation 'std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>::_Is_string_view_ish<_StringViewIsh>' being compiled
        with
        [
            _StringViewIsh=const wchar_t *
        ]
```

Do you know how to check if a key exists that has a value of type array?

Comment: why don't you show the error, it probably contains useful information;-)

Answer (score 1):

Found a different way to do this, using object_t:

```
tao::json::value v = tao::json::parse_file("..\\json.json");
std::map<std::string, tao::json::value, std::less<>> o = v.get_object();

{
auto i = o.find("name");
if(i != std::end(o))
{
    std::cout << i->second.get_string();
}

auto i = o.find("NOT_FOUND");
if(i != std::end(o))
{
    std::cout << i->second.get_string();
}
else
{
    std::cout << "NOT_FOUND";
}
}
return 0;
```

This works find and will be a clean way to find if an object is missing or not.